# passing an ID with a coldfusion element into a jQuery function

Tags: jquery, coldfusion

I am attempting to eventually create this page that will show a relative hidden list of data when a "plus" or "minus" image is clicked next an element that contains the list. Right now, as a button is clicked, all of the other buttons change in addition to the clicked button. I know this is because the .click() method is attached to every img with the src=plus.gif or src=minus.gif. However, I cannot figure out how to pass the correct img id into my function.

```
<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {

    $("img[src='plus.gif']").click(function () {
        $("img[src='plus.gif']").toggle();
        $("img[src='minus.gif']").toggle();
    });

    $("img[src='minus.gif']").click(function () {
        /*$("#siteList").toggle();*/
        $("img[src='plus.gif']").toggle();
        $("img[src='minus.gif']").toggle();
    });
});
</script>

<h1><cfoutput>#qOrgSite.BUSINESS#</cfoutput></h1>

<cfloop list="#keysToStruct#" index="i">
    <cfoutput>
        <img src="plus.gif" id="plusImg_#i#" alt="" border="0">
        <img src="minus.gif" id="minusImg_#i#" alt="" border="0" hidden>
        <strong>#busStruct[i].name#</strong><br>
        <div id="siteList" hidden>
            <cfloop array="#busStruct[i].site#" index="j">

                <cfoutput>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;#j#<br></cfoutput>

            </cfloop>
        </div>
    </cfoutput>
</cfloop>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would strongly suggest you look into the [.data()](http://api.jquery.com/data/) jquery element.

Here is one possiblity of how you could use it in your code:

```
    <script>
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        $(".plusMinusImg").click(function () {
            thisId = $(this).data("id");
            console.debug(thisId);
            $("#Section"+thisId).find(".plusMinusImg").toggle();
            $("#Section"+thisId).find(".siteList").toggle();
        });

    });
</script>


<cfloop list="#keysToStruct#" index="i">
    <cfoutput>
        <div id="Section#i#">
            <img src="plus.gif" data-id="#i#" class="plusMinusImg" alt="" border="0">
            <img src="minus.gif" data-id="#i#" class="plusMinusImg" alt="" border="0" hidden>
            <strong>#busStruct[i].name#</strong><br>
            <div class="siteList" hidden>
                <cfloop array="#busStruct[i].site#" index="j">
                    <cfoutput>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;#j#<br></cfoutput>
                </cfloop>
            </div>
        </div>
    </cfoutput>
</cfloop>
```

Comment: thanks for the advice. definitely makes things a lot cleaner and easier.

Answer (score 1):

Always try to wrap repeating modules in a container. Then it is easy to traverse only within that container to isolate instances

```
<cfoutput>
     <div class="myModuleContainer">
        <img class="icon-plus" src="plus.gif" id="plusImg_#i#" alt="" border="0">
        <img class="icon-minus" src="minus.gif" id="minusImg_#i#" alt="" border="0" hidden>
        <strong>#busStruct[i].name#</strong><br>
        <div id="siteList" hidden>
            <cfloop array="#busStruct[i].site#" index="j">

                <cfoutput>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;#j#<br></cfoutput>

            </cfloop>
        </div>
   </div>
</cfoutput>
```

Then in your event handlers `this` is the element that the event occurred on

```
$("img.icon-plus, img.icon-minus").click(function () {
    $(this).closest('.myModuleContainer').find('.icon-plus, .icon-minus').toggle();        
});
```

Comment: Great help! Thank you vary much!